# Compilation Error with XDocument

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-xml

I have been working on a website for a car dealer. When getting the website ready to go live we came to the realization that the server they use is set up with the 3.5 framework and unfortunately I had built the site in 4.0 not 3.5. After changing the site over I now get a Compilation Error.

```
 Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service    this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Line 99:      //query the database to search for New cars only     
 Line 100:     XDocument feed = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("VEHICLES.XML"));
```

I think the error is that I am calling my assembly references in the code behind file and then calling XDocument within the page itself so I can run the search and then Response.Write the results right onto the page. This works in 4.0 but in 3.5 it seems to not be able to find the assembly. I did not use a repeater for this because I needed to check certain things, such as if the car is certified or not as I list them on the page so I can make changes, this didnt seem to work with a repeater.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this error or how to go about it more effectively I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You haven't said what the compilation error is, which doesn't help...

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the top of the class...

```
Using System.Xml.Linq
```

If you still get the error, add the System.Xml.Linq.dll reference to your project.

Comment: I am referencing it in the code behind. But on the actual page its throwing the error.

Comment: Your PROJECT (with the line of code that has the error) has System.XML.Linq.dll as a reference and you have the Imports statement on the top of that code file?

Comment: yeah if i try and add the reference I get an error saying its been added already, and I already have the Using System.Xml.Linq statement at the top of the file, I assume thats the same as Import seeing Import doesnt work for me.

Comment: Edited for C# (Using).  I'm assuming you've Cleaned and Rebuilt the solution a couple times, but I'll throw that out as a suggestion just in case.

Comment: yeah ive tried that a few times, going to restart it now although i doubt thats the case. Stranger things have happened though.

Comment: I am inclined to think that there's something wrong with your code that is not included in the code you've provided. It should be working - just for kicks, have you tried importing the System.Xml namespace too?

Comment: Try to remove and add reference again. May be you project referencing library from framework 4